# pandas.DataFrame.replace() method doesn't replace anything when using a variable in regex

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I'm currently working with pandas to edit CSVs. Thing is I have a "product template" csv, I need to make one for each products changing some fields to match the product (for example the name). With that logic I made in the CSV what I would call a var looking like this: `*shape`

To replace the "variables" I use this method:

```
df.replace([fr"(\*{key})+"], value, inplace=True, regex=True)
```

But it doesn't replace anything (`key` is equal to the variable name and `value` is equal to what it should be replaced by), but when I do the following :

```
df.replace([r"(\*product_name)+"], dir, inplace=True, regex=True)
```

It does replace correctly the string by what I want (`dir` is the value variable so value can be a variable with no issues).

I already tried to use `.format()` method to insert the variable into the regex but none of what I tried worked and I'm starting to think it's maybe related to my regex (it just needs to replace all matching strings by the value).

EDIT :

Here is some sample data to give more context :

`meta.json` which is where I get `key` and `value`

```
    "data": [
        {
            "R\u00e9f\u00e9rence interne module fini": "MODCA-0000004",
            "Longueur (mm)": 42,
            "Largeur (mm)": 12.0,
            "Epaisseur (mm)": "1,0mm",
            "Courant (mA)": "350mA",
            "Tension (V)": "12-14V",
            "Puissance (W)": 4,
            "Nbre Led": 4,
            "Marque LED": "CREE XPG2",
            "Boitier Led ": 3030,
            "CCT (\u00b0K)": "3000\u00b0K",
            "IRC": ">90",
            "Connectique": "Pad",
            "C\u00e2ble": "2* 20cm UL1007 24AWG",
            "Compatibilit\u00e9 lentille": "Carclo 10417 REV1",
            "Couleur PCB": "Blanc"
        }
    ]
```

I use pandas with this def :

```
def meta_exporter(exec_dir, template):
    exec_list = os.listdir(exec_dir)
    for dir in exec_list:
        with open(f"{exec_dir}/{dir}/meta.json") as meta:
            meta_json = json.load(meta)
            for data in meta_json["data"]:
                csv_template = pandas.read_csv(template, encoding="utf8")
                df = pandas.DataFrame(csv_template)
                for key, value in data.items():
                    try:
                        df.replace([fr"(\*{key})+"], value, inplace=True, regex=True)
                    except Exception as e: 
                        return print(colored("[SKDE]", "blue"),colored("There was an error: ", "green"),colored(e, "red"))
                    df.replace([r"(\*product_name)+"], dir, inplace=True, regex=True)
                df.to_csv(f"{temp}/csv/{dir}.csv", encoding="Windows-1252")

meta_exporter(exec_dir, template)
```

`exec_dir` is where I execute the script (the script scan the exec_dir to detect folders)

`template` is equal... to the csv template I use...

And the CSV template I am using : https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1AJeBM3sifjc-Qh684XlwR3VnOBFmjr3JBTFa7qAc91s/edit?usp=sharing

All the variable have a * before for example `*product_name`

Comment: Replace the entire STR with a single variable and try

Comment: using `df.replace(str, value, inplace=True)` doesn't replace as well, the only way replace worked for me was to use regex

Comment: And doing the following doesn't replace as well :

`parsed_key= fr"*{key}"`
`print(parsed_key)`
`df.replace(parsed_key, value, inplace=True)`


but the print actually print the exact same str as the one I want to replace in the csv

Comment: I use ```df.replace([r"(\*product_name)+"], dir, inplace=True, regex=True)``` and failed

Comment: This one does work in my CSV, it's only when using variables that it doesn't

Comment: can you add a example

Comment: `df.replace([r"(\*product_name)+"], dir, inplace=True, regex=True)` doesn't use a variable, I don't know what you tried to make it fail but it works perfectly on my side, but for example `df.replace([fr"(\*{product_id})+"], value, inplace=True, regex=True)` which is very similar (except the fact that `product_id` is a  random number `product_id = randrange(100000)` ) doesn't replace `*product_id` on the csv

Comment: Could you edit your question to include a few rows of sample data for others (like myself) to try and reproduce your issue?

Comment: Yeah sure, I will do it

Comment: Cannot reproduce. If I use your meta_json, and the sample csv, the keys are replaced in the Tags column

Comment: That's kinda... weird, the CSV is indeed strange (sadly i'm forced to use one like that cause Wordpress...). When you say they are replaced in tags you mean that the replacement works in the tags column but not in the others?